# How to scroll through history in Terminal.app and Vim?

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, scroll

I have problem with scrooling through command history in Terminal.app. Looks like something clear them.

Take a look on screencast.(video) => http://www.screencast.com/t/JgrQv5XNOH

Comment: What do you want us to see in this screenshot?

Comment: Like you can see I have option ``Scrollback`` set to ``Limit to availiable memory``

Comment: You probably have 4 or 5 GB available. Even with 100 MB left you would have enough for a few days worth of usage.

Comment: So where to find reason why I cant see that history?

Comment: Try `gnu screen` copy-mode instead of using mouse.

Comment: Hi, yes gnu screen copy-mode works but I have to scroll using arrows and I would like to use mouse. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was SIMBL + MouseTerm.